# Missing "Find and Replace" menu and right click "Find All References" VS2015 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015

New workplace, new machine. VS2015 Enterprise was already set up. Seems to be missing the entire "Edit, Find and Replace" menu (just has "Quick Find" and "Quick Replace" Also missing is the right click "Find All References" (there's a "Show all references on CodeMap" option instead).

I suspect it was set up with a VB.Net user default, and that might be an issue, but I'm not sure and I can't recall how to change it ... Or am I looking at a reinstall?

Can any kind person help?